# SIGSEGV in while(*(txt+k)!='\\0') when sending

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Im supposed to make function that reverse words in string. Everything seemed nice but debugger is showing SIGSEGV

```
#include <stdio.h>
void removeChar(char *str, char garbage) {

    char *src, *dst;
    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; src++) {
        *dst = *src;
        if (*dst != garbage) dst++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
void reverse(char* begin, char* end)
{
    char temp;
    while(begin<end){
        temp=*begin;
        *begin++=*end;
        *end--=temp;
    }
}
char* swap_order_words(char* str)
{
    char* txt;
    if(!str && !txt)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(str != NULL)
    {
        txt = str;
    }
    if(*txt == '\0')
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(txt=NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    int k=0, lit=0;
    while(*(txt+k)!='\0')
    {
        if(*(txt+k)>=65 && *(txt+k)<=90){
            lit++;
        }
        if(*(txt+k)>=97 && *(txt+k)<=122){
            lit++;
        }
        if(!(*(txt+k)>=65 && *(txt+k)<=90) && !(*(txt+k)>=97 && *(txt+k)<=122) && !(*(txt+k)==32)){
            removeChar(txt,*(txt+k));
        }
        k++;
    }
    if(lit<1){
        return NULL;
    }
    char* start=txt;
    char* stop=txt;
    while(*stop){
        stop++;
        if(*stop=='\0'){
            reverse(start,stop-1);
        }
        else if(*stop==' '){
            reverse(start,stop-1);
            start=stop+1;
        }
    }
    reverse(txt,stop-1);
    return txt;
}
int main ()
{
    char str[1001];
    char str_z_nothing_to_show[]={"Nothing to show"};
    printf("Podaj tekst: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%1000[^\n]", str);
    char * ver;
    ver = swap_order_words(str);
    if(ver==NULL){
        printf("%s", swap_order_words(str_z_nothing_to_show));
        return 0;
    }
    printf ("%s",ver);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a debugger, so why not actually _use_ it, to see _where_ the segfault occurs, and inspect values of variables in the run-up to reason about _why_ it does?

Comment: Aside: please stop using 'magic numbers' and make the code portable and readable with `'A'` etc, and/or the use of library functions such as `isupper()` etc.

Comment: Tip: `*(x+y)` is better written as `x[y]` as in `*(txt+k)` should be `txt[k]`.

Comment: `char* txt` is a pointer with an uninitialized value. `if (... !txt)` is undefined behaviour. There is a *lot* of little mistakes in this code, and C is ruthless about doing exactly what you say, not what you mean, so the responsibility is on you to be very careful.

Comment: You *really* need to test these functions individually before assuming they work and then packaging them up into this giant chunk of code.

Comment: Aside from paxdiablo's answer, if you `removeChar` the very last character, and then `k++`, as you do, the check in the `while` loop will now check beyond the terminator.

Comment: A decent compiler should warn you about making an assignment in a condition. If you do not get some warnings with your code, you should urgently tune up diagnostics level. For GCC this can be done with `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: In the line `if(!str && !txt)` `txt` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `if(txt=NULL)` is *not* a comparison, it's actually *setting* `txt` to a null pointer. A comparison would be `==`.

Hence, when `k` is zero, `*(txt+k)` will be a null pointer dereference, a *very* good candidate for the cause of your SIGSEGV.

Keep in mind that, even when you *fix* that, you've never actually *set* `txt` to be a specific value before first using it, so what it contains will be some arbitrary value, meaning that behaviour is also arbitrary.